# Error al insertar registros en una tabla temporal de una consulta remota de un Store Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en SQL Server 2008, y el problema que tengo es que no puedo (No sé si en realidad sea posible) insertar registros provenientes de una consulta de un *Store Procedure* de otro servidor:

```
declare @DRIVER Table 
(drive char(1), FreeMB int)

INSERT  @DRIVER
EXEC DYSNOMIA.MASTER..xp_fixeddrives
```

**ERROR:**
"OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "DYSNOMIA" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".

Mens. 7391, Nivel 16, Estado 2, Línea 4

The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "DYSNOMIA" was unable to begin a distributed transaction."

*Aunque si me funciona si solo ejecuto le procedimiento de forma remota (La última línea)*

***Datos Adicionales de Configuración:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega datos del error. La inserción de datos desde un Sp remoto es posible.

Comment: Hola, he añadido mas detalles del problema.

Comment: Hay que habilitar "Distribute Transaction Coordinator" en ambos servidores y si mal no recuerdo, los linked Server tenen que tener configurado las opciones de "RPC", Fijate [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767/the-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions)